# Error when instantiating WinJS.UI.ListView with template from code

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-8.1, winjs

In the process of creating a custom WinJS control which contains a `WinJS.UI.ListView`, I was attempting to allow a user to pass a selector for the template.

However, no matter if I have the template "pre-created" in the HTML page like you would expect:

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template"> <!-- ... --> </div>
```

Nor if I query for the element and create the template from code like:

```
var template = new WinJS.Binding.Template(document.querySelector(selector));
```

When I get to instantiating the ListView and pass in the template element itself (or its `winControl` property) to the ListView's `itemTemplate` option, as such:

```
new WinJS.UI.ListView(elem,  { itemTemplate: template.winControl });
```

I receive the following error:

> Exception is about to be caught by JavaScript library code at line 11562, column 21 in ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.2.0/js/base.js
>
> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method '_renderItemImpl'

I attempted to trace it back a bit but am getting lost in `base.js`. Hoping someone else has run into this.

Note: I've included my workaround as an answer.

Comment: Also please note I omitted other options from the ListView instantiation example above as I presume them to be irrelevant to the question, but I am using layout of ListLayout, selectionMode of none, and a static itemDataSource.

Comment: I'm curious, what selector are you using to reference the template? Typically one uses either an id or a class on the template <div> and references that with the selector.

Comment: @KraigBrockschmidt-MSFT I was using a class name at the time. I know I was able to retrieve the element fine, as I was able to validate the `winControl` property on the retrieved element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only workaround I've been able to get to work is to instantiate the template in code, then pass a function to the `itemTemplate` option when instantiating the ListView. The documentation on what is expected here is sparse, but all of the demos where the ListView is instantiated via code use a templating function so I presume this is the only way to achieve this sadly.

```
new WinJS.UI.ListView(elem,  {
    itemTemplate: function (promise) {
        return promise.then(function (item) {
            return resultsTemplate.render(item.data);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the declarative markup for the `Binding.Template` has been processed before you try to use it. You can process declarative markup with `WinJS.UI.processAll()`.

If you are creating both the `ListView` and `Binding.Template` declaratively, make sure the `Binding.Template` appears first in your markup so that it is done being processed by the time the `ListView` tries to consume it.

[Check out this sample](http://try.buildwinjs.com/#listview:create) which creates a ListView and template with declarative markup.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply, but this did not work for me either. The solution I posted is still the only thing that works for me.